# check file attributes in a C program

Tags: c, unix

ALL,

AFAIK, `chmod`  function change the file attributes in c programme.

Is there any function in c that gives you the opportunity to check(get) or compare file attributes?

what i want in  my program is testing before executing a file whether or not it has the right x for u and g (user and group)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) which will return information on a given path.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct stat FileAttrib;

    if(argc <= 1)
    {
        printf("Argument missing!\n");
        exit(10);
    }

    if (stat(argv[(argc - 1)], &FileAttrib) < 0)
        printf("File Error Message = %s\n", strerror(errno));
    else
        printf( "Permissions: %d\n", FileAttrib.st_mode );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`stat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to find out permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - Try stat - http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

This will retrieve the details (and more) that you require

Answer (score 1):

Call `int stat (const char *filename, struct stat *pStat)` and pass stat structure.
You can inspect pStat->st_mode to find out file permission bits.